# Client/Server Application for iOS

Tags: ios, json, rest, https, client-server

I have had experienced with iOS development but no Client Server type applications.

I have heard about HTTPS, REST, JSON, etc. I am confused on the differences.

My app that I want to build is getting a list of data to output to the user and also sending a form to the server to be processed. E.g. A Membership Application to the Server with personal information and other pertaining information to be stored in the server. I also need the connection to be secure and the user must logon to the server with a username and password.

How does my app communicate with the server? Is it using NSURLRequest?

What is the best method or protocol to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are several libraries for higher level protocols on top of tcp/ip. At the lowest level though, to get a good understanding of network programming you need to start with berkley sockets api. The berkly socket api is available on any POSIX system, including BDS, and mac ios (which is BDS based).

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ is a good starting place for information.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS, REST, and JSON are different tools you can use when performing networked operations (more specifically, a secure protocol, a web service architecture, and a method of object serialization, respectively). If you don't know what these mean, I would do a little reading before attempting to build an iOS app that functions as a client. The link johnathon posted in the comments is a little low-level for what you're wanting to do, but searching around for "consuming a web service with iOS" might be good.

Also, does the service already exist? If so, your task is essentially to understand how to communicate with the server.

Once you're a little more up-to-speed on the fundamentals, however, the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) library is phenomenal.

Comment: There is a server, but right now it has no specific implementation to commmunicate with iOS devices. It just has a web interface, but that's about it.

Comment: while the link may be "low level" there are layers that are even lower than the Berkley api. With that said it's always a very useful thing to understand the underlying architecture that any protocol is built on top of. More importantly the guide does go into the structure the client server model. While your answer more targets the higher level protocols that the OP is questioning, IMHO not understanding how it all works leads to very poorly written applications. As with any aspect of programming, it's always best to build a fundamental understanding of the tools at hand.

Comment: And , judging by the OP's comment, he needs that fundamental understanding of networking and network api.

Comment: johnathon, I totally agree with you. Unfortunately, most people are just looking to obtain a working knowledge instead of fully understanding the tools they're working with. While the latter definitely is better, I'm assuming the OP just wants to get up and running.

Comment: I agree with both of you. I am not actually designing the server. I just need some idea on how to interface with the server with my app. Thank you both.